# What is the difference between disabling and removing a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Over time, I have installed several Chrome extensions on my Chrome browser. I disabled many of them. I have read in some articles that it is good to remove the seldom-used extensions. I am not sure whether I should disable or simply remove the extension.

What is the difference between disabling and removing a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Difference 1:

- `disabling` an extension means it is intalled but `not enabled`
- `uninstalling` an extension means that it is not enabled because it is `completely removed`

##### Difference 2:

- a `disabled` extension can be enabled simply by `enabling it`
- to enable an `uninstalled` extension, you must `reinstall it`

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Is there a difference in terms of browser security and performance?